# Modify "Recent Comments" List in WP-Admin

Tags: comments, wp-admin

This one might be a little tricky, but I'm looking for a way to make the Recent Comments widget on the wp-admin a bit more useful/action-driven. I'd like to be able to filter to only show the Pending comments (as those would require an action to them). I saw on line 45 of `wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php` there is:

```
// Recent Comments Widget
    if ( is_blog_admin() && current_user_can('moderate_comments') ) {
        if ( !isset( $widget_options['dashboard_recent_comments'] ) || !isset( $widget_options['dashboard_recent_comments']['items'] ) ) {
            $update = true;
            $widget_options['dashboard_recent_comments'] = array(
                'items' => 5,
            );
        }
        $recent_comments_title = __( 'Recent Comments' );
        wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dashboard_recent_comments', $recent_comments_title, 'wp_dashboard_recent_comments', 'wp_dashboard_recent_comments_control' );
    }
```

but I'm a little fuzzy on the correct way (or if there is a way) to hook into this to modify the "types" of comments shown. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a hook/filter available to control comments displayed in the widget. You might have to create new dashboard widget for this as new plugin or as part of themes function.php